# Maven Non-parseable POM for spring-boot-dependencies

Tags: java, spring, maven, dependencies, pom.xml

Trying to setup an elementary Spring boot app, using Win10, Eclipse (Photon 4.8.0), maven 3.5.3 within Eclipse, and following [this tutorial](https://dzone.com/articles/creating-a-spring-boot-project-with-eclipse-and-ma)

The error is the following :

`Non-parseable POM C:\Users\user\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-dependencies\2.1.3.RELEASE\spring-boot-dependencies-2.1.3.RELEASE.pom: in epilog non whitespace content is not allowed but got s (position: END_TAG seen ...</build>\n</project>\ns... @3189:2)`

I've tried various suggestions such as clearing cache, checking the encoding, etc. but as a beginner I have no idea where to look at

pom.xml :

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.myproject</groupId>
  <artifactId>myproject</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
</properties>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.3.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>


<dependencies>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
</dependencies>

</project>
```

Comment: Have you tried deleting your local Maven repository directory, "C:\Users\user\.m2", and then rebuilding?

Comment: Delete your local cache and turn on checksum policy and rebuild... https://blog.soebes.de/blog/2018/10/13/maven-artifact-checksums-what/

Comment: @ck1 yep I have tried that

Comment: @khmarbaise this solutions suggests to edit the settings.xml file (I'm discovering what this is as we speak), I have no settings.xml because it is not created by default, can you tell me more about this file and what if I create one manually with only the tags I about the checksum policy ?

Comment: @Temps Read the link I've posted.

Answer (score 0):

`in epilog non whitespace content is not allowed but got s (position: END_TAG seen ...</build>\n</project>\ns... @3189:2` :

You should re-check your pom (spring-boot-dependencies-2.1.3.RELEASE.pom), i think that you have the character **'s'** 
after the tag : `</project>`

Comment: Is this an issue with the encoding ? If I write any character after </project>, the error will indicate that the file ends with </project>blahblah, no 's' character. I've opened the pom.xml file with notepadd++ and tried to save it with different encoding (UTF8, UTF8 BOM), but the error is still there

Comment: i have edited my answer, i thinks that  the file spring-boot-dependencies-2.1.3.RELEASE is corrupted try delete it from your .m2 folder letting Maven redownload it on the next build.

Comment: Other ways this issue could occur is if you have an old Maven version

Comment: @AbdessattarNOISSI has nothing to do with an old Maven version. This is based on network issues and a corrupted pom/jar file or multiple of them...

Comment: Hey thanks for your replies. I use the maven within eclipse (3.5.3). I've emptied the .m2 directory, reloaded Eclipse, now the error is about `glassfish\jersey\jersey-bom` and `fasterxml/jackson/jackson-parent` `can not have PITarget with reserved xml name`. Again I have no idea what I'm looking at nor how to play around with maven settings. Thx for your help !